# htaccess redirect when directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For making friendly URLs, Following is the htaccess code applied:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1    [NC,L,QSA]  
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
```

This now works for:

1. `mydomain.com/pages` to `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages`
2. `mydomain.com/pages/xyz` to `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages&id2=xyz`

also, when I enter `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages&id2=xyz` manually in the URL, it redirects to `mydomain.com`.

Now, when I enter another like `mydomain.com/templates` where templates is a directory that exists, it redirects to `mydomain.com/templates/?id1=templates`

**Edit 1:**

I tried adding this line but in vain:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

How shall I avoid this condition (when directory with that name exists) using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
#serve dirs without rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]    
#####
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1    [NC,L,QSA]  
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I get the same results.. I tried with yours and the with the edited text in the question.