# htaccess redirect fails to redirect when directory exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For making friendly URLs, Following is the htaccess code applied:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1    [NC,L,QSA]  
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
```

This now works for:

1. `mydomain.com/pages` to `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages`
2. `mydomain.com/pages/xyz` to `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages&id2=xyz`

also, when I enter `mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages&id2=xyz` manually in the URL, it redirects to `mydomain.com`.

Now, when I enter another like `mydomain.com/templates` where templates is a directory that exists, it redirects to `mydomain.com/templates/?id1=templates`

I tried adding these lines but in vain:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

My directory structure:

```
www/
    .htaccess
    index.php  <--- main router
    templates/
            img/
            css/
            ...
            ...
    other_directories/
    ...
    ...
```

`index.php` should receive id1 and id2.

How shall I avoid this condition (when directory with that name exists) using htaccess?

***Note:*** This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835920/htaccess-redirect-when-directory-exists). But posting again, as it didn't gain considerable views nor answered the issue!

Comment: Is your directory's (like templates) static or dynamic?

Comment: Directories are static right? it resides in the filesystem location

Comment: you can add the directory's which dont want to redirect in; RewriteRule ^(templates|another_directory)($|/) - [L]

Comment: Thanks.. But I could see that home directory's index page is not still pointed.. its pointing templates directory (I enabled directory listing, so it displays the directory contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force a trailing slash in front of directories using a redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?id1=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think I don't have any changes.. still redirecting to templates directory

Comment: Yes I am doing everytime, its displaying `mydomain.com/templates/` but executes the index page inside templates directory

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Never Tested

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the director's are static     
# Redirect exclude for templates, also can add the aonther directory's
RewriteRule ^(templates|another_directory)($|/) - [L]    

# Redirect General
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ index.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?id1=$1 [L]
```

**Result**

mydomain.com/pages/ = mydomain.com/index.php?id1=1

mydomain.com/pages/xyz = mydomain.com/index.php?id1=pages&id2=xyz

It wont redirect for mydomain.com/templates/ and mydomain.com/another_directory/

Comment: This is listing the contents of templates...! - Not this I want

Comment: I have updated the question with directory structure

Answer (score 0):

If /templates is an existent dir, you can exclude it using a RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates [NC]
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)$    index.php?id1=$1    [NC,L,QSA]
```

or you can use the following rule before your other rules to pass the uri unchanged:

```
RewriteRule ^templates - [L]
```

Comment: I have updated the question with directory structure